# Point Backendless object to user

Tags: android, parse-platform, backendless

I'm migrating to Backendless from Parse and is currently trying to do something that was pretty obvious with Parse.

I'm creating a class:

```
@ParseClassName("UserPreferences")
public class UserPreferences extends ParseObject {

     public ParseFile getBackground(){
         return getParseFile("background.jpg");
     }

     public boolean getAudioStatus(){
         return getBoolean("audio");
     } 
     public void setAudioStatus(boolean status){
     put("audio", status);
     }
}
```

Now I want to assign this class to the currently logged in user as a pointer:

```
UserPreferences userPrefs = new UserPreferences();
userPrefs.setAudioStatus(true);
ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
user.put("prefs", userPrefs);

userPrefs.saveInBackground() 
user.saveInBackground();  //again, use SaveCallback
```

and to retrieve all values etc to be applied to local preferences:

```
ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
UserPreferences userPrefs = user.getParseObject("prefs");
userPrefs.fetchInBackground();
```

This way, the user's data is always tied to himself and objectID etc isn't a problem.

Now I didn't work this out myself when using Parse. So unfortunately I can't really talk for this matter. I just hope someone more experienced see's what I'm doing and can relate this into translating it to Backendless SDK and workflow somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need to extend any specialized Backendless classes in the objects you save/load to/from Backendless. In the classes you can use either public fields or getter/setter properties. You do not need to use any annotations. Things are much simpler. If you have a class A which references class B (via a field or a javabean property), then on the backend, we will store A in a table called "A" and B in a table called "B". We will also create a relation between the two records on the backend.

There are two ways you could handle what you showed with Backendless:

**Saving user object with preferences:**

```
BackendlessUser user = Backendless.UserService.CurrentUser();
user.setProperty( "audioStatus", true );
user.setProperty( "backgroundImageUrl", url-to-background-jpg );
Backendless.UserService.save( user, asyncCallback );
```

This will result in creating two columns in the Users table: "audioStatus" and "backgroundFile". If, however, you want to have a separate table where all the preferences are, you could do this:

```
public class UserPreferences 
{
  // or use Java bean getter/setter instead of fields
  public String backgroundImageUrl;
  public boolean audioStatus;
}

UserPreferences prefs = new UserPreferences();
prefs.backgroundImageUrl = url-to-background-jpg;
prefs.audioStatus = true;    
BackendlessUser user = Backendless.UserService.CurrentUser();
user.setProperty( "userPrefs", prefs );
Backendless.UserService.save( user, asyncCallback );
```

This will result in a secondary table created on the backend. The table will be called "UserPreferences" - just like the class name. Backendless will also create a relationship between the user object and the specific record in the UserPreferences table.

**Retrieving user properties**

If the user properties are not stored via a relation (see the first sample above), then they are loaded right away when the user logs in. Then you can get the properties with the getProperty method:

```
 Backendless.UserService.login( userName, password, new AsyncCallback<BackendlessUser>()
    {
      @Override
      public void handleResponse( BackendlessUser user )
      {
        boolean audioStatus = (boolean) user.getProperty( "audioStatus" );
        String fileUrl = (String) user.getProperty( "backgroundImageUrl" );
      }

      @Override
      public void handleFault( BackendlessFault backendlessFault )
      {

      }
    });
```

If the preferences are stored in a related table, then you have several options to load them:

```
BackendlessUser user = Backendless.UserService.CurrentUser();
ArrayList<String> relations = new ArrayList<String>();
relations.add( "userPrefs" ); // name of the relation column in Users
Backendless.Data.of( BackendlessUser.class ).loadRelations( user, relations, new AsyncCallback<BackendlessUser>()
   {
     @Override
     public void handleResponse( BackendlessUser user )
     {
       // user - object with loaded relations. 
       // now you can do this:
       UserPreferences prefs = (UserPreferences)user.getProperty( "userPrefs" );
     }

     @Override
     public void handleFault( BackendlessFault backendlessFault )
     {

     }
   });
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Outstanding Mark. Couldn't ask for a better explanation! Thank you, for your superior service and support.